# How to point another domain to specific path on an existing website in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5, url-mapping, multiple-domains

So i have an existing site running fine in IIS, let's call this domain www.mysite.com.  Now there is a folder on the site that is basically a sub-site, that folder is 'foundation'. So I need to point an additional domain at this folder, the additional domain will be www.mysitefoundation.com.

I know how to add domains and such in the Bindings of IIS, but my brain is stuck on how to get a new domain pointing at a particular FOLDER.

I have lots of urlMappings setup, but they don't relate to the new 'foundation' domain. For example I have lots of these:

```
<add url="~/community" mappedUrl="~/Company/Community"/>
```

So how do I make it work like this:

Original site www.mysite goes to root/home as usual. While newly added www.mysitefoundation.com goes to what is basically www.mysite.com/foundation?

Clear as mud?! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match using the `HTTP_HOST` condition

```
<rule name="RedirectToFoundation" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysitefoundation.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mysite.com/foundation/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Yep - that's the route I went with - only rather than in the web.config I chose to do it via IIS. Thank you!