# IIS10 Get domain to point to particular subfolder

Tags: iis, dns, iis-10

I have a site, example.com, which also has in its bindings examplegroup.com. I now need to get the examplegroup.com domain to point to 3 particular folders within the www folder, eg reports2021, reports2022 etc, but only them. I have googled and found this solution but it's in IIS7.5. Will this still be valid for IIS10?

[How to point another domain to specific path on an existing website in IIS 7.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345289/how-to-point-another-domain-to-specific-path-on-an-existing-website-in-iis-7-5)

eg

```
<rule name="RedirectToFoundation" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="examplefoundation.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/foundation/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

*(The other SO thread used mysite)*

However it's a bit different in that I have 3 or more folders I need to point to, eg, examplegroup.com/reports2021 points to the reports2021 folder (and **example**.com/reports2021 redirects to **examplegroup**.com/reports2021) and then the same for reports2022 etc etc. So how would I set these up? Thanks

(I haven't tried anything yet as this is not really something I can experiment with in advance and I need to be able to quote for the job so trying to figure it out to give the client an idea.)

Answer (score 0):

you could try below rule to implement your requirement:

```
<rule name="test rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(reports2021|reports2022|reports2023)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://examplegroup.com/{C:0}" />
                </rule>
```